# How to add a decimal to the xml of a webservice>?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, sql-server-2008, asmx

I have a .asmx webservice I created in Visual Studio 2010 with vb.net.  I recent modified the query below and added ", geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326).STDistance(Location) * 0.00062137119".  Since I added that I need to add to the while reader.Read() Loop to output the decimal as a string on the xml for the webservice The line fuelStop.Distance = reader.GetString(5) obviously will not work what can I do to output the distance to the xml?

Webservice code:

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Function GetFuelStops(ByVal Latitude As Double, ByVal Longitude As Double) As FuelStop()
    Dim resultList = New List(Of FuelStop)()

    Using sqlCon As New SqlConnection()
        sqlCon.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=My_DB;User ID=*****;Password=*******"
        Dim sql = <sql>
            DECLARE @center GEOGRAPHY

            SET @center = geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326)

            SELECT TOP 10
                [Physical_Address_Street]
                , [Physical_Address_Local]
                , [Physical_Address_State]
                , [Physical_Address_Zip]
                , [Phone_Number]
                , geography::Point(@Latitude, @Longitude, 4326).STDistance(Location) * 0.00062137119
            FROM Gas_Stations
            WHERE Location_Type = 1
            ORDER BY @center.STDistance(Location) ASC
            </sql>
        Dim command As New SqlCommand()
        command.CommandText = CStr(sql)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Latitude", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Latitude
        command.Parameters.Add("@Longitude", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = Longitude
        command.Connection = sqlCon
        sqlCon.Open()

        Using reader = command.ExecuteReader()
            While reader.Read()
                Dim fuelStop = New FuelStop()
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Street = reader.GetString(0)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Local = reader.GetString(1)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_State = reader.GetString(2)
                fuelStop.Physical_Address_Zip = reader.GetString(3)
                fuelStop.Phone_Number = reader.GetString(4)
                fuelStop.Distance = reader.GetString(5)



                resultList.Add(fuelStop)
            End While
        End Using
    End Using
    Return resultList.ToArray()

End Function
```

And here is my FuelStop.class

```
Public Class FuelStop

    Property Physical_Address_Street As String

    Property Physical_Address_Local As String

    Property Physical_Address_State As String

    Property Physical_Address_Zip As String

    Property Phone_Number As String

    Property Distance As String

End Class
```

Comment: reader.GetDecimal(5).ToString() ?

To be honest, you should just change your fuelstop.class to have Distance as a decimal, it'll be serialized properly anyway. (and don't use .ToString() )

Comment: Ok so I changed the FuelStop Distance to a decimal, and when I call with the reader should I do a reader.getDecimal(5)?

Comment: Yes, as it will get the value as a Decimal.  This should then correctly be serialized to the XML output.

Comment: Ok so I did that and when I debug my webservice and get to the fuelStop.Distance = reader.GetDecimal(5) the webservice returns a page cannot be displayed and it just never shows anything other than that.

Comment: How is the distance defined in your database?

Comment: My bad, you are calculating it as a STDDistance - which is a float.  You might want to use type of float and reader.GetFloat(5) instead.

Comment: Once I defined it as a Double it was fine, just kinda strange that Visual Studio didn't throw the error but the webpage did.

Comment: (Added my comments as an answer to get this off the unanswered list, if you would be so kind as to mark it answered? )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to read a float as a string, you should use the correct type to get it from the reader:

reader.GetDecimal(5)

and put the correct type in your class that is to be returned.

(As determined in the comments, you found it Double would work :) )

The serialization of things other than strings will still appear correct in the XML (for the most part).

Comment: Thanks for the comment, and the answer.  I am more of a Java guy trying to get into Visual Basic and C#.  I appreciate it.